# Removing Vocals from sound file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I am separating left and right channels of sound files using Matlab. The code compiles but it is not removing the vocals completely from the sound file. Why is that?

Here is the code:

```
 [y,fs]=wavread('On the floor.wav');

 left=y(:,1);
 right=y(:,2);


 wavplay(left-right,fs);
```

Comment: What do you hear on the right, what do you hear on the left?

Comment: The vocals are suppressed a little bit but they are not completly gone. How can I do that? Am I missing something in this code

Comment: And how can I stop the sound play while the file is being played in matlab. I have tried `clear playsnd` in workspace but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm surprised you even have some success with this. If it's really that straightforward, try `left-2.0*right` or find an `f` that minimizes `abs(left-f*right)` to then calculate `left-f*right`. You can also truncate `y` like in `y=y(1:ceil(size(y,1)/10),:)` to only work with the first 10th of the song.

Comment: Ok can you tell me how can I stop the music while it playing matlab

Comment: ^Type clear in the console.

Comment: Separating the audio into left and right only separates the song in 2 pieces (imagine 2 microphones recording the song at the same time). If you want to separate audio from background I strongly recommend you to read this paper: http://music.cs.northwestern.edu/publications/Rafii-Pardo%20-%20REpeating%20Pattern%20Extraction%20Technique%20(REPET)%20A%20Simple%20Method%20for%20Music-Voice%20Separation%20-%20TALSP%202013.pdf
This paper is about REPET Technique. It consists in the idea that te voice is a non-periodic signal mixed with a periodic signal (background). Using Hamming windows it is pos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vocal suppression is a *hard* problem that is the subject of a great deal of academic and commercial research.   In academia this kind of problem is called *source separation* and in recent years has been a popular doctoral research subject;  a large body of literature consequently exists.

The approach you are appear to be implementing is to subtract programme material in the centre of the stereo image.  When implemented (see comment above) correctly, this may well suppress some of the the vocals on some tracks but will also large amounts of other material that is mixed into the centre that you would wish to retain.